# How to show given products only using product id array from specific category page in woocommerce

Tags: categories, woocommerce-offtopic

I would like to show only the list of product ids in the tax query using `woocommerce_product_query` filter.

So I need to add an additional filter along with a tax query to filter to show only products with given ids.

```
$tax_query[] = array('add filter to show only specified products');
$q->set( 'tax_query', $tax_query );
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I somehow misunderstood your question, but you don't need the `tax_query` for that, just use the

```
$ids = array( <ID1>, <ID2>, ... );
$q->set( 'post__in', $ids );
```

Comment: Hi Ivan
Thanks for your quick response and it is working.
Great Thanks